# How do I access and view cache HTML5 videos located in Safari or Chrome cache?

Tags: macos, safari, video, google-chrome

I want to view and possibly remix a video on youtube.  I have seen many demos and articles describing where the cache is on older versions of the browsers, but now it seems that Safari is stored in a .db file, and I haven't figured out chrome.

How can I extract and save an HTML5 file in a way so that I can view it later, or edit it in a video editing program?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to download a video, you can use [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

Downloading a YouTube video with Safari:

1. Enable using the HTML5 player from https://www.youtube.com/html5.
2. Enable the develop menu from Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar.
3. Select Develop > Show Page Resources.
4. Reload the page.
5. Double-click the `videoplayback` resource.
6. Focus the location bar and press option-return.